# Странное поведение после рефакторинга

Tags: c#

```
al.Add(RandomClass.CreateRandomString());
foreach (var s in al)
    Console.Write("{0}\t", s);
```

Если этот кусок находится в Main, то все нормально. При перемещении в метод другого класса и последующим вызове метода через экземпляр класса, элементы коллекции неоднократно дублируются при выводе на консоль. Но при этом если запросить кол-во элементов коллекции, выводится правильное число(без учета дублированных членов).

Это работает корректно

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
Console.Write("Введит количество элементов коллекции: ");
int collectionLength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
stopWatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < collectionLength; i++)
    al.Add(RandomClass.CreateRandomString());
foreach (var s in al)
    Console.Write("{0}\t", s);
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Время заполнения коллекции: {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
Console.WriteLine("Количество элементов в коллекции: {0}", collectionLength);
```

А это нет

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
ArrayListWrapper al = new ArrayListWrapper();
Console.Write("Введит количество элементов коллекции: ");
int collectionLength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
stopWatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < collectionLength; i++)
    al.AddElements();
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Время заполнения коллекции: {0}",      stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
Console.WriteLine("Количество элементов в коллекции: {0}", collectionLength);
```

Код в ArrayListWrapper

```
class ArrayListWrapper : ICollectionWrapper
{
    ArrayList internalArrayList = new ArrayList();
    public void AddElements()
    {
        internalArrayList.Add(RandomClass.CreateRandomString());
        foreach (var s in internalArrayList)
            Console.Write("{0}\t", s);
    }
```

Comment: Из main удалили тестовый код? В целом лучше весь код прикладывать

Comment: скорее всего случайно два раза вызываете вывод коллекции. пробовали отладить?

Comment: Добавил код. Дублирующий код не удалял, а закомментировал

Comment: код размещен в конструкторе? есть ли потоки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код неэквивалентен:

Первый пример `collectionLength` раз добавляет элемент. Потом выводит все элементы

```
(n раз добавить)

вывести все
```

Второй - n раз добавляет элемент, и *после каждого* добавления выводит *все* элементы

```
(n раз)
{
    добавить 1 элемент
    вывести все элементы
}
```

Т.е. он

- Добавляет один элемент. Выводит его.
- Добавляет еще один элемент. Выводит оба элемента.
- Добавляет еще один элемент. Выводит все три элемента.

Рефакторинг не должен изменять функционал, так что у вас - не рефакторинг :)

Или вынесите foreach с выводом элементов из `AddElement`, или выводите в `AddElement` толко последний добавленный.

Кстати, `ArrayList` - это древнее наследие .NET 1.0, оставленное только ради совместимости. Используйте `List<T>`.

Comment: спасибо. на счет ArrayList, цель протестировать производительность коллекций.